# unable to load google map in my ionic app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

i am trying to add google map in my ionic app. i have successfully added the map using below code  in am ionic project. but when i  try to integrate that map with my ionic app it doesn't show any thing and console is also empty.i have also included cordova plugin.

index.html

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es"></script>
```

style.css

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  height: 100%;
}

.buttonclass{
    width: 18%;
    height:18%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

- html part:

  ```
  <ng-view>
  <body ng-controller="MapCtrl">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
        <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
      </ion-content>
      <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
        <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
      </ion-footer-bar>
    </body>
  </ng-view>
  ```

controllr.js

```
    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                mapOptions);

            //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
            var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
            var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: compiled[0]
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            $scope.map = map;
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
            if (!$scope.map) {
                return;
            }

            $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                content: 'Getting current location...',
                showBackdrop: false
            });

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
                $scope.loading.hide();
            }, function(error) {
                alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
            });
        };

        $scope.clickTest = function() {
            alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
        };

    })
```

Comment: check your console for error

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Console shows nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, I made working demo from your code.

[https://codepen.io](https://codepen.io/hirojaisinghani/pen/QKYVYV)

HTML

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
   <style>
    .editable-image {
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;


}
    #map {
     height:200px;
     width:600px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

      <ion-tab title="Map" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-football" href="#/tab/about">
        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-bag" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
        <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h2>Google Map</h2>
        <div id="map"></div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Facts">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
        <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
        <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
        <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
        <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
        <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
        <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
        <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
        <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
        <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/mylongform.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-modal-view class="product edit create">
          <form name="itemEdit" novalidate>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive fix-buttons">
              <a class="button" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</a>
              <h1 class="title">Form</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content has-bouncing="true">
              <div class="row" ng-class="{'no-padding-top': !data.editItem}">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="item item-input large">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Title">
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="editable-image horizontal-image">
                <div class="add"><i class="icon ion-upload"></i>
                  <div class="instructions">Tap to upload photo</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="item item-input large">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Price">
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row description-row">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="item item-input text">
                    <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="5" ng-model="item.description" ng-Required="true" name="description" lose-focus-on-return></textarea>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row charity-row">
                <div class="col col-10 vert-center">
                  <div class="charity large"></div>
                </div>
              </div>


            </ion-content>
          </form>
        </ion-modal-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="About">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
        <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
        <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="Contact">
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item">
            @IonicFramework
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            @DriftyTeam
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

IONIC Controller JS Code

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('tabs', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
      })
      .state('tabs.home', {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
          'home-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.facts', {
        url: "/facts",
        views: {
          'home-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.facts2', {
        url: "/facts2",
        views: {
          'home-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/facts2.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.about', {
        url: "/about",
        views: {
          'about-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.navstack', {
        url: "/navstack",
        views: {
          'about-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.contact', {
        url: "/contact",
        views: {
          'contact-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
          }
        }
      });


     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

  })

  .controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {


  function initialize() {

              var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388);

              var mapOptions = {
                  center: myLatlng,
                  zoom: 16,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                  mapOptions);


              //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
              var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
              var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: compiled[0]
              });

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: myLatlng,
                  map: map,
                  title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
              });

              $scope.map = map;
              console.log(map);

          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

          /* $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
              if (!$scope.map) {
                  return;
              }

              $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                  content: 'Getting current location...',
                  showBackdrop: false
              });

              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                  $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
                  $scope.loading.hide();
              }, function(error) {
                  alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
              });
          }; */

          $scope.clickTest = function() {
              alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
          };
  });
```

Comment: Please make sure that in your index.html not contain the <!DOCTYPE html> tag. If contain then remove that tag from your index.html file.
Please check and let me know if you face any issue in that.
Thanks